# Half-life of $W$ and $Z$ bosons

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction, electroweak, strong-force, half-life

$W$ and $Z$ bosons should decay through **weak** interaction. But their half-life is around $\tau = 10^{-25} s$ which is a typical value for particles decaying through **strong** force (instead of a $10^{-12}-10^{-6} s$ for a weak interaction decaying particle).
Why this can be?

Comment: The microsecond decay of a muon reflects a small rate. In your particle physics course you learned that the relevant matrix element for that is determined by a minuscule phase space and a minuscule matrix element, weighed down by the virtual W propagator. For the W decay, both of these fail: *no* W propagator suppression. Proceed to estimate the phase space by dimensional analysis. Correlating lifetimes with interaction types is not a sacrosanct rule, only a rule of an *old* thumb.

Comment: Thank you. So it is correct to say that the W boson is decaying through weak interaction despite its very small lifetime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it *is*

> correct to say that the W boson is decaying through weak interaction despite its very small lifetime.

The weak interactions were dubbed such in the last century because, at low energies compared to the mass of the *W*, about 80GeV, the large mass of this particle appeared squared in the propagator of this virtual particle in all weak process amplitudes. This is summarized in the Fermi constant *G* of the relevant amplitudes. Thus, weak decay widths involve the square of *G*. 
As a result, virtually by dimensional analysis, e.g., *μ* decay *must be* of order ${\cal O} (m_\mu^5 /m_W^4)$! Recall the mass of the *μ* is ~ 0.1GeV, so a thousand times smaller than that of the *W*. (It is a 2-scale problem: the electron and neutrinos' masses are negligible here.) So, all low-energy weak processes are "cursed" by such a suppression.

As you probably covered/will cover in your particles physics course, the actual ***small*** width for *μ* decay giving it its long, microsecond, lifetime, is
$$
\Gamma_\mu \sim \frac {G^2 m_\mu ^5}{192 \pi^3}=\frac{g^4 m_\mu^5}{m_W^4 \pi^3 ~6144},
$$
where *g* is the usual EW coupling.

Now, contrast this with the *real W* decay into *μ ν*, where there is ***no propagator suppression***:
$$
\Gamma_{W\to \mu\nu} \sim g^2 m_W /48\pi , 
$$ 
whose order you find again by dimensional analysis: it *has* to be $m_W$, as it is a one-scale problem---all other scales are negligible.

The ratio of the two, then, amounts to 
$$
\frac{m_\mu^5}{m_W^5} ~ \frac{g^2}{128\pi^2}
$$
and so 20 orders of magnitude. And you thought these leaps only happen in astronomy...

You may also marvel at the power of the SM electroweak unification which leads you to such  sensible descriptions across 20 orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

Both are weak decay processes but the intermediate vector boson decay occurs at very much higher energies of 80-90  GeV compared to 1 GeV for beta decay.

Comment: @flippiefanus indeed, I shouldn't.